# Is loading and saving an image using QImage loss-less?

Tags: qt

Do I potentially lose data when I load an image-file into a QImage and then re-save it? Or is it loss-less in the absence of any transformations/editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect this depends on the format. For example, [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a compression algorithm, which is then uncompressed into the QImage. Saving again may not create a lossless image here, especially as the degree of compression can be changed.

However, if you use a raw image format, such as [png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics), the data is likely to be the same when saving and re-reading in the image back into a QImage.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on what you mean by lossless. If the image file format is lossless (say, PNG), then a disk->QImage->disk roundtrip only guarantees the persistence of the image's bitmap. Non-image data (attributes, etc.) won't be preserved.

If the image format is *not* lossless (say, JPEG), then the roundtrip will in fact degrade the quality of the image.

You need to think what `QImage` would need to do in order to support lossless roundtrip for bitmaps. It would need to store not only the decoded image bitmap, but also the contents of the source file. The latter would need to be discarded once any modification is done to the image. It wasn't implemented since it would be a premature pessimization that would potentially double the memory usage of `QImage`.

You're free to implement a `QImage`-lookalike that would behave the way you want. Do note that you should be properly supporting the copy-on-write semantics, and your image file data internally must be kept in `QSharedData` and accessed via a `QSharedDataPointer`. You'd need to forcibly `detach` this data in all non-const methods.